# Want help with MVC 3 creating custom validators in a better way on Collection properties

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, customvalidator

I am stuck with creating the custom validators to satisfy our project's buisness rules.

Now below given is the model :

public class CreateTestModel
    {
        public CreateTestModel()
        {

```
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string BucketValidator { get; set; }

    public RadioButtonListViewModel<GoalTypes> Goals { get; set; }

    [EntityValidator(Property1:"IncludedEntities",Property2:"ExcludedEntities",MandatoryCount:1,isBucket=false, ErrorMessage = "One Entity is Compulsory")]
    public IEnumerable<TestEntityModel> IncludedEntities { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<TestEntityModel> ExcludedEntities { get; set; }


    public int MandatoryEntityCount { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<TestFilterModel> IncludedFilters { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<TestFilterModel> ExcludedFilters { get; set; }
  [EntityValidator(Property1:"Buckets",Property2:"",MandatoryCount:2,isBucket=true,ErrorMessage = "Bucket is compulsory")]

    [DisplayName("BucketErrors")]

    public IEnumerable<BucketModel> Buckets { get; set; }

    public bool AutoDecision { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public int AdminId { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

upon the above given model i created the Entity validator which is used to satisfy my business rules .But since the validation is to be taken place on the collection properties the Validator fails to put in the error when there are more than one value in the collection, else it checks in the errors generated.

EntityValidator class is as given below :

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]

```
public class EntityValidator : ValidationAttribute,IClientValidatable
{
    public int numberOfMandatoryEntities{get; private set;}
    public int totalCountofIncludeEntities { get; private set; }
    public bool isBucket { get; set; }
    public string Property1{get; private set;}
    public string Property2{ get; private set; }
    private const string DefaultErrorMessageFormatString = "Atleast one entity is required";

    public EntityValidator(string Property1, string Property2, int MandatoryCount)
    {
        this.Property1 = Property1;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Property2))
            this.Property2 = Property2;
        numberOfMandatoryEntities = MandatoryCount;
    }

    public EntityValidator(string Property1,string Property2,int MandatoryCount,bool isBucket)
    {
        this.Property1 = Property1;
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Property2))
        this.Property2 = Property2;
        this.isBucket = isBucket;
        numberOfMandatoryEntities = MandatoryCount;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format(ErrorMessageString, name);
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        object property2Value = null;
        object property1Value = null;
        int property1Count=0;
        int trafficCount = 0;
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Property2))
        property2Value = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(Property2).GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
        property1Value = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(Property1).GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
        if (property1Value != null)
        {
        property1Count = ((IEnumerable<Object>)property1Value).Count();
            if (isBucket)
            {

                IEnumerable<BucketModel> bucket = ((IEnumerable<BucketModel>)property1Value);

                var result = bucket.Select(x => x.TrafficPercentage);
                foreach (var i in result)
                {
                    trafficCount = trafficCount + i;
                }
            }

        }
        if(isBucket)
        {
            if(trafficCount<100)
            {
                var x = new ValidationResult(string.Format("Percentage total cannot be less than 100 %", validationContext.DisplayName));
                return x;
            }
        }
        if (property2Value != null)
        {
            property1Count = property1Count +((IEnumerable<Object>)property2Value).Count();
        }
        if (property1Count < numberOfMandatoryEntities)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
    #region IClientValidatable Members

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var x = new ModelClientValidationRule();
        x.ValidationType = "entityvalidator";
        x.ErrorMessage = string.Format(ErrorMessageString, metadata.GetDisplayName());
        x.ValidationParameters.Add("mandatoryentity", numberOfMandatoryEntities);
        x.ValidationParameters.Add("checkforbucket", isBucket);

        return new[] 
        {  
            x
        };
    }
```

Now the Problems are :

1) When there are more than one values in the collection the IsValid returns the error but it is not spotted bound to any property in ModelState ! Adding a pseudo property is an option but what is the better way than that ?

2) Taking this validator client side is easy by adding pseudo properties for each rule and specifying the function in the clientvalidationrules, and adding the adaptor to validated.
But this approach doesnt seem very appropriate and just seems a workaround, is there any better way to do so ??

Please help ... ! Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

When validation rules get complicated as in your case I would recommend you leaving data annotations and head over to [FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) which has a great [integration with ASP.NET MVC](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc) (I use it all the time, not only when validation rules get complicated). As far as client validation rules are concerned, it supports most of the common rules but when it gets complicated you are better of writing custom adapters.

Comment: Thanks ! I am looking that through before using it with my project . But one more problem with this kind of validator is that this when working with collections having more than one value when debugged the custom validator return IsValid as false but this is not able to plug in the error to the respective properties .. ! Now how to work this out ??